# Product of functions with finite chaos expansion is in $L^2(P)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, malliavin-calculus

I'm reading the book "Malliavin Calculus for Lévy Processes with Applications to Finance".

At one point the authors prove that the Leibniz rule holds for the Malliavin Derivative $D_t$ taken at functions in $\mathbb{D}_{1,2}^0$, which is the subset of $L^2(P)$ consisting of those functions with only finitely many nonzero terms in their Wiener-Itô Chaos expansion.

It is clear that if $F\in\mathbb{D}_{1,2}^0$, then $F\in\mathbb{D}_{1,2}$, which is the space of functions such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nn!\|f_n\|_{L^2([0,T]^n)}^2<\infty$, where $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} I_n(f_n)$ is their chaos expansion.

Now they state that if $F_1,F_2\in\mathbb{D}_{1,2}^0$, then $F_1\cdot F_2\in L^2(P)$, and they say this is because the Gaussian random variables have all finite moments.

This doesn't seem trivial to me. How do I derive this from the fact that Gaussian random variables have all finite moments?

Answer (score 0):

I think they just mean that if

$$F_1=I_0(f_0)+...+I_n(f_n)$$
$$F_2=I_0(g_0)+...+I_m(g_m)$$

Then:

$$\Bbb E(|F_1 F_2|^2)=\Bbb E(\sum \text{bunch of iterated integral products})=\sum\Bbb E (\text{bunch of iterated integral products})<\infty$$

The sum is finite because you're taking expectation of Gaussian RVs, which have finite moments of all orders.